# What do the square brackets mean in an ubuntu terminal command's synopsis?

Tags: command-line

For the 'find' command, the synopsis from

```
man find
```

is:

```
find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [path...] [expression]
```

What do the square brackets mean? I used to think they just meant an argument or flag was optional, but [path...] and [expression] can't both be optional for find, right...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What do the square brackets mean?

Square brackets in a command synopsis mean optionality (i.e. whatever is listed inside of them is optional / not required in order to run the command).

> I used to think they just meant an argument or flag was optional, but [path...] and [expression] can't both be optional for find, right...?

They can; running `find` without `[path...]` and `[expression]` just prints the list of folders / files in the current working directory's hierarchy without any condition.

---

The `[<expr>]` construct along with other symbols / constructs commonly used in command synopses (e.g. `|`, alternation, and `{<expr>}`, repetition) are the same used to define formal languages in [Extended Backus-Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) (EBNF), so EBNF's syntax is a a good reference to understand / remember what symbols / constructs in command synopses mean.